# Move files across computers with command line (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, network-shares

I have a VM running XP on which files get uploaded at random moments. 
I need a script or utility fit for the command line, that would run every X minutes (for instance) and **MOVE** all uploaded files to a shared dir on a Win7 box.

Now, the command-line `move` command doesn't run across drives, even less so across shares.
(And it gives the super helpful message `Access denied.`)

I could do a

```
copy src desr_share
rm src
```

...but here's the tricky part:

When the copy command runs, it may happen that a file is uploaded at the same time. The `copy` may upload just a chunk of the file, or skip it completely and move on, but later, when the `rm` kicks in, the file may be completely uploaded, and the `rm` will erase it, without it having been properly copied to the destination.

So I need something that has the `move` semantics (copy a file and delete it only if successful), but that would work across machines.

Any suggestions?

PS. I don't mind if a file gets only partially moved, as long as it's not then deleted. I will force overwriting any destination files, and on the next run, the file will be uploaded again, completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into Robocopy, which is standard on Win7 and is available in a microsoft dev kit for xp.

use `robocopy /?` (or `robocopy /? > drive:\path\robocopy_options.txt`) for options.

Windows 7:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Windows XP:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657#Requirements

Comment: Nice. What I used is:> robocopy src dst /move /e